# EXCEPTION CPMessageException: (null) in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I'm new in iPhone, I'm trying to open .doc file in the UIWebView, I wrote the following code

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.doc", docName] ofType:nil]; 

NSLog(@"in search the document url address: %@", urlAddress);

NSURL *url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

the application doesn't crash, but it gives me the following:

```
EXCEPTION CPMessageException: (null)
```

and loads a blank page

Any Help in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these two SO posts:
[Reading Open-XML documents in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131430/reading-microsoft-word-document-in-iphone)
[any objective-c library to parse/read word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849144/any-objective-c-library-to-parse-read-word-documents)