# Read contents of a DOC (.docx or .doc) file and convert it to String

Tags: ios, swift, docx, doc

I need help on reading a DOC (.docx or .doc) file's contents and display it inside the UILabel. The file is from the URL, so I download the file to DocumentsDirectory and in the process of finding a solution to read the contents.

I am using `Alamofire.download` and I have called:

```
let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: (response.destinationURL?.path)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

but it is returning `nil`

Does anyone know how to read the contents of a doc file would be appreciated.

Comment: try to replace `String.Encoding.utf8` to `String.Encoding.ascii`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131430/reading-open-xml-documents-in-ios etc.

Comment: @a.masri I used .ascii and I get a lot of characters like ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ\u{01}\0þÿ\u{03}\n\0\0ÿÿÿÿ\u{06}\t\u{02

Comment: @LawGimenez : Not all files can be "translated" as a String. Just try to read a UIImage as a String, you can't really. You can print the hex data, but it's not done for that. .doc & .docx are private format. You might find libs for that (if you want good one, you might have to pay for it). Usually a UIWebView can render them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [SNDocx](https://github.com/ahmedAlmasri/SNDocx)

OR

Doing this is not as easy as you imagine,
a docx file is a zipped up collection of XML and other files. You can't load a docx file into an `String`. You would need to use `Data` to load the `zip` contents. Then you would need to `unzip`  it. Then you would need to go through all of the files and find the desired `word/document.xml` then read xml and parse .

Im use [Zippy](https://github.com/clemens-schulz/Zippy)

Look this code

```
 guard let originalFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "docx") else {
            print("file not found :( ")
            return
        }
     do{

           let filename = try! ZipFile.init(url: originalFileURL)
            // file name  content 
            //            - 0 : "[Content_Types].xml"
            //            - 1 : "word/numbering.xml"
            //            - 2 : "_rels/.rels"
            //            - 3 : "word/theme/theme1.xml"
            //            - 4 : "word/fontTable.xml"
            //            - 5 : "word/document.xml"
            //            - 6 : "word/settings.xml"
            //            - 7 : "word/styles.xml"
            //            - 8 : "word/_rels/document.xml.rels"

            for file in filename {
                if file.contains("document.xml"){
                    let data = filename[file]
                    print(String.init(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
                }
            }

        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
```

**Output**

*`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r<w:document xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math\" xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" xmlns:w10=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:wne=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml\" xmlns:sl=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main\" xmlns:pic=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture\" xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart\" xmlns:lc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas\" xmlns:dgm=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram\" xmlns:wps=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape\" xmlns:wpg=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup\" xmlns:w14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml\" xmlns:w15=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml\"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR=\"00000000\" w:rsidDel=\"00000000\" w:rsidP=\"00000000\" w:rsidRDefault=\"00000000\" w:rsidRPr=\"00000000\" w14:paraId=\"00000000\"><w:pPr><w:contextualSpacing w:val=\"0\"/><w:rPr/></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidDel=\"00000000\" w:rsidR=\"00000000\" w:rsidRPr=\"00000000\"><w:rPr><w:rtl w:val=\"0\"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">test</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:sectPr><w:pgSz w:h=\"15840\" w:w=\"12240\"/><w:pgMar w:bottom=\"1440\" w:top=\"1440\" w:left=\"1440\" w:right=\"1440\" w:header=\"0\"/><w:pgNumType w:start=\"1\"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>`*

You have to parse xml  this and you will find in the my output that it must be parse until this value is obtained

*`<w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">test</w:t>`*

[docx XML Format reference](https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx)

Comment: Can you explain to me the  throwing error  is made  any line of code ?

Comment: maybe it was because the file is a doc document and not a docx

Comment: let me check it

Comment: @LawGimenez I'm sorry , but as explain to me the difference between doc and docx, you can not read doc. You must convert doc to docx so that we can read the content.

Comment: yes that's what I thought, I will accept this answer once I get to confirm using a docx